# R has erased files

Tags: restore, r

The few last weeks I've been working on two R files. I have a tendency to save my files every minute, so I have done that for sure at least once per day.

Yesterday, while working in R on a (shared) remote desktop connection, R froze. Therefore, I closed the program and opened it again this morning. Now, two `.R` files that I had opened up are empty, but another `.R` file that was opened still contains all its code.

Even when I try to restore to an older version in the file explorer, even there the older versions of my files are empty. Furthermore, the R environment that I was working with is still in tact.

Who can tell me what has happened and if there is a way to somehow retrieve my files again?

Comment: If you are on Windows (?), try the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Thanks. The Recycle Bin does not have these files. I think this is because the files aren't removed, they are just empty. So all the content is erased, but they are still in the same location.

Comment: In Explorer, right-click the file, choose Properties and then Previous Versions. If this doesn't work, then the question is if this is important enough to do a lot of work.

Comment: That's what I have tried as well, and surprisingly the previous versions show the file as well, but in all of these versions the file is empty as too. What could I do/ terms can I look for to go for a lot of work?

Comment: Do you have any backup solution in place so you could try to restore to an even earlier version?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I'm on a server that is being moderated by my organization. If the restoring process is something that the moderator of the server needs to do, then I guess it's better if I start writing the code again.

Comment: "A lot of work" means using programs that will scan the disk in the hope that the data is still somewhere. But I agree that it's maybe better to start writing the code again (and next time have backups).

Comment: I know this isn’t much comfort after the fact, but this is why you should use a version control system such as Git.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are not in the Recycle Bin, and if you cannot find them by
in Explorer, right-click on the file, Properties and "Previous Versions",
and if you don't have backup, then this is the end of the line for those files.

Next time ensure taking a backup every day, if the editor is that untrustworthy.
Using a version control system such as Git could also help.

You should complain loudly to the developers.